# Como implementar sodium-native en angular 5

Tags: javascript, nodejs, angular, typescript

Tengo este script el cual crea un hash correctamente en node.js.

```js
const sodium = require("sodium-native")
 
let msj = 'saludos'
let seed = "987654321"
let opslimit = 1
let out = Buffer.alloc(93, "hex")
let salt = Buffer.from(seed, "hex")
let memlimit = sodium.crypto_pwhash_MEMLIMIT_MIN
let alg = sodium.crypto_pwhash_ALG_ARGON2ID13
 
let message = Buffer.from(msj)
 
sodium.crypto_pwhash(out, message, salt, opslimit, memlimit, alg)
 
console.log(`msj: ${msj}`)
console.log(`Hash argon2 msj: ${out.toString("hex")}`)
```

Lo que necesito es hacer lo mismo pero usando angular 5.2.10 y typescript 2.4.2

En el proyecto que tengo con angular instale
"buffer": "^5.6.0",
"buffer-alloc": "^1.2.0",
"buffer-from": "^1.1.1",
"sodium-native": "^2.4.6",

Pero al momento de tratar de importarlos no lo logró, este es el primer problema que tengo

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { bufferFrom } from 'buffer-from'
import { Buffer } from 'buffer'
import { Alloc } from '../../../node_modules/buffer-alloc'


import * as sodium from 'sodium-native'
import { Sodium } from 'sodium-native';

@Injectable()
export class HashArgon2Provider {

  constructor(
     public  buffer: bufferFrom,
     public bufferI:Buffer,
    public alloc:Alloc,
    public Sodium
    
  ) {
   
    
    console.log('Hello HashArgon2Provider Provider');
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que he encontrado

- La librería sodium-native es un *wrapper* en Javascript para el uso en NodeJS de la librería [libsodium](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium).
- El "native" del nombre ya debería darnos pistas de lo que ocurre: la librería `libsodium` está escrita en **C**, por lo que `sodium-native` realmente lo que hace es llamar a las funciones de esta librería y obtener el resultado para ser usado dentro de NodeJS... por lo que no es portable a un navegador.
- De los mismos [autores](https://github.com/sodium-friends/), existe también la librería [sodium-javascript](https://github.com/sodium-friends/sodium-javascript), que es una librería equivalente escrita puramente en Javascript. El problema de esta librería es que aún está en fase de desarrollo (WIP, Work in progress) lo que significa que  no está muy testeada y que ciertas funcionalidades no están implementadas a día de hoy (Agosto 2020). Dependiendo de lo que necesites, es posible que puedas usarla.

Nota: Parece que la librería sodium-javascript no soporta ES6 modules, por lo que no puedes importarla usando `import {..} from ...`. Ya que la librería parece estar pensada para usarse en el navegador, quizá sería bueno pedir a los desarrolladores que cambien el sistema de dependencias  para descartar el uso de `require(...)` típico de NodeJS.

Comment: Comprendo puedes indicarme la documentación donde dicen esto:sodium-javascript no soporta ES6 modules, estaba leyendo en https://github.com/sodium-friends/sodium-universal, pero especifica eso

Comment: Este script es para usarlo en ionic 3, para una app mobile.